# How to set in edittext? If value is not given, it does not pass to next page

Tags: android, android-activity, android-edittext

Here is my code. In this code I give some values to edittext, and it passes to the next page. If I didn't give any value to that edittext, it gets "FORCE CLOSED". I want to set edittext in such a way that if I didn't give any values, it must show a toast that says "give some value and submit".

Here is the code...

```
  Button damage = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_damage_reason);  
  damage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override

        public void onClick(View v) {



            Intent i = new Intent(Unloading.this, DamageReason.class);

            i.putExtra("count", dmg_cyl_recvd.getText().toString());
            startActivity(i);



        }

    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this

```
String editTextString = dmg_cyl_recvd.getText().toString();
if( editTextString != null && editTextString.length() > 0)
{
  //go to next view
}
else {

// show toast
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do this before starting the next activity:

```
EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id. dmg_cyl_recvd);
//I'm assuming that dmg_cyl_recvd is the id of your edit Text

String input = editText.getText().toString();

//check if editText does not have anything
if(input.equals("")){
    input = 0;
}

//if it's not empty, then just put it as an extra in your intent then start intent
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
if(!(yourEditText.getText().toString().equals(""))){
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "give some value and submit", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check like this..

```
  String value=edittext.gettext().toString();
  Button damage = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_damage_reason); 
 damage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
    if(value.length() <= 0){
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "give some value and submit",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        edittext.requestFocus();
    }
    else{
     Intent i = new Intent(Unloading.this, DamageReason.class);
     i.putExtra("count", dmg_cyl_recvd.getText().toString());
     startActivity(i);
         }
     });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
  Button damage = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_damage_reason);  
  damage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override       
    public void onClick(View v) {           

        Intent i = new Intent(Unloading.this, DamageReason.class);              
        i.putExtra("count", dmg_cyl_recvd.getText().toString());

         if(dmg_cyl_recvd.getText().toString() != null) {               
             startActivity(i);             
          } else {
           // log condition
           }

    }           
});
```